# groupby result is inconsistent in polars

Tags: python, python-polars

in the user guider, there is an example:

```py
from datetime import date

def compute_age() -> pl.Expr:
    return date(2021, 1, 1).year - pl.col("birthday").dt.year()

def avg_birthday(gender: str) -> pl.Expr:
    return compute_age().filter(
            pl.col("gender") == gender
        ).mean().alias(f"avg {gender} birthday")


q = (
    datasetn.lazy()
    .groupby(["state"])
    .agg(
        [
            avg_birthday("M"), 
            avg_birthday("F"),
            (pl.col("gender") == "M").count().alias("# male"), 
            (pl.col("gender") == "F").sum().alias("# female"),
        ]
    )
)
df = q.collect()
df
```

the result is inconsistent.
for example ：run by the first time:

| state | avg M birthday | avg F birthday | # male | # female |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| str | f64 | f64 | u32 | u32 |
| ME | 58.0 | 67.5 | 4 | 2 |
| AZ | 60.375 | 59.666667 | 11 | 3 |
| VT | 78.333333 | null | 3 | 0 |
| GU | 40.0 | null | 1 | 0 |
| KS | 54.2 | 41.0 | 6 | 1 |
| LA | 58.0 | 40.0 | 8 | 1 |

for example ：run by the second time:

| state | avg M birthday | avg F birthday | # male | # female |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| str | f64 | f64 | u32 | u32 |
| NC | 56.181818 | 69.0 | 15 | 4 |
| MA | 60.0 | 56.25 | 11 | 4 |
| CO | 57.428571 | 49.5 | 9 | 2 |
| IA | 70.0 | 52.75 | 6 | 4 |
| CA | 57.323529 | 67.75 | 54 | 20 |
| ME | 58.0 | 67.5 | 4 | 2 |
| NV | 55.5 | 61.75 | 6 | 4 |

I guess it may cause by paralleling?
Is this a bug or a feature?
How to keep the result consistent?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `maintain_order=True` on [`groupby`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/api/polars.DataFrame.groupby.html).

> maintain_order: Make sure that the order of the groups remain consistent. This is more expensive than a default groupby. Note that this only works in expression aggregations.

(As an aside, I'm not sure where you got the `squeeze=True` argument in your post.)

> .groupby(["state"], squeeze=True)

Comment: sorry, I have tried the `squeeze=True` argument for pandas, I haved edited the Question. Can I ask you what's the difference between `groupby` and `over`？

Comment: `over` "broadcasts" an aggregate over the rows.  For example, if you have 5 records with the same group key and you want to calculate the mean for some variable, `over` will return all 5 records but create a new column with the group mean repeated on each record in the group.  This would, for example, allow you to subtract the mean of the group from each individual observation.  `groupby` is intended to return only one record for each group key.

Comment: thx so much! So the `groupby` method is often used with `agg` to get a result with only one value per group (per row). And the group name in `over` is repeated for each group, which means that `over` is more suitable for performing some operations on the values in each group.
Also, I would like to ask, `.sort().groupby()`, the real order is execute `groupby` first and then execute `sort`?

Comment: @lemmingxuan please read the user guide. Especially the [window function](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars-book/user-guide/dsl/window_functions.html) section explains `over`.